# Amazaon AWS EC2 taking ages to load

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I created an instance (I created many instances before) and it is telling me

> Password generation and encryption can sometimes take more than 30
>   minutes. Please wait at least 15 minutes after launching an instance
>   before trying to retrieve the generated password

It has been over a day since I created it and its not letting me enter my password decryption.

What is wrong?

Comment: You can check the system log, but you might as well just fire up a new one.

Comment: The thing is that I have some data on it which I don't want to lose.

Comment: How can you have data on it if it's an instance you just created and have never been able to get into?

Comment: Its a 'copy' of another instance.

Comment: What'd you do with the original? Chances are if something went wrong on instance creation for the copy you're not going to be able to get into it.

Comment: I lost my password key. I tried to access it but I couldn't so if I create a copy I will be able to access the copy thanks to obtaining a new password.

Comment: I'd re-copy the original instance, then. If you still don't get a password after a while, contact AWS support.

Comment: I tried it. The told me I have to be premium for support. Cheeky bummers.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an AMI, you won't be able to get your password. You will need the password that was set on the original instance.

Comment: Ouch :-S Is there any other way to recover it?

Comment: You could use the .net SDK from AWS to decrypt the password with your keypair as follows:


string rsaPrivateKey;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\keypairs\beta.pem"))
{
    rsaPrivateKey = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
GetPasswordDataResult result = ec2Client.GetPasswordData(
    new GetPasswordDataRequest()
    .WithInstanceId(instanceId)).GetPasswordDataResult;
 
Console.WriteLine(result.GetDecryptedPassword(rsaPrivateKey));


From here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=68395